# TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' mnist

Tags: python

someone can help me here, I can not solve this problem.

```html
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=False)

dataWithLabels = zip(mnist.train.labels, mnist.train.images)

digitDict = {}

for i in range(0,10):
    digitDict[i] = []
    
for i in dataWithLabels:
    digitDict[i[0]].append(i[1])

for i in range(0,10):
    digitDict[i] = np.matrix(digitDict[i])
    print("Digit {0} matrix shape: {1}".format(i,digitDict[i].shape))




---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-05052c24d917> in <module>()
 15 # Assign a list of image vectors to each corresponding digit class index.
 16 for i in dataWithLabels:
---> 17     digitDict[i[0]].append(i[1])
 18 
 19 # Convert the lists into numpy matricies. (could be done above, but I claim ignorace)

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Comment: Only immutable types (like a tuple) are allowed as dictionary keys (or set elements) and therefore hashable.

Comment: seems ``mnist.train.labels`` is not of size (x,), i.e not 1D but 2D of size (x,1). Make it ``digitDict[int(i[0])]``

Comment: @DeepakSaini I did what you recommended and I get the following error

Comment: TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what shape the labels take. Try the following options:

- `i[0]` (like you already have)
- `i[0][0]` (in case they're 1-length arrays)  <== this is my best guess
- `float(i[0])`
- `float(i[0][0])`

If none of those work, please provide us `mnist.train.labels.shape`

Comment: it seems that it was that, no longer throws error, but do not leave the amount of elements that there are per class.And thanks for the help.

Comment: Digit 0 matrix shape: (49556, 784)
Digit 1 matrix shape: (5444, 784)
Digit 2 matrix shape: (1, 0)
Digit 3 matrix shape: (1, 0)
Digit 4 matrix shape: (1, 0)
Digit 5 matrix shape: (1, 0)
Digit 6 matrix shape: (1, 0)
Digit 7 matrix shape: (1, 0)
Digit 8 matrix shape: (1, 0)
Digit 9 matrix shape: (1, 0)

Comment: Sounds like a separate issue from the indexing problem. Consider opening a new question if you have a different bug now.